# I have system low volume efi error issue. How to resolve this issue? This is not related to removing old kernels in my case I think

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, kernel, uefi

Whenever I boot into Ubuntu, I get this error " System low volume EFI error" and I am attaching the graphic associated with it.  I want to know how to fix this issue. Hoping someone can help me remove the unwanted files from the /boot/efi as I couldn't find this process elsewhere. [image]

Answer (score 0):

There is not much to be eliminated in a tiny 100mb partition. Though mine only shows 11M in use.

```
root@zeus-H370M:~# fdisk -l /dev/sda | grep sda1
/dev/sda1      40    409639    409600   200M EFI System
root@zeus-H370M:~# df -h | grep sda1
/dev/sda1       200M   11M  190M   6% /boot/efi
root@zeus-H370M:~# efibootmgr -v |grep ubuntu
Boot0004* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9fad4e77-177d-4a3c-929a-3897e6bc1810,0x28,0x64000)/File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)
root@zeus-H370M:~# du -h /boot/efi/
6.6M    /boot/efi/EFI/Boot
4.2M    /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu
11M     /boot/efi/EFI
11M     /boot/efi/
```

Use the efibootmgr to determine which directories you need left in the `/boot/efi` partition to be able to boot and delete them ones not needed. Mine above shows I need `File(\EFI\UBUNTU\SHIMX64.EFI)` to be able to boot, so I cannot delete the `/boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu`. Edit and you are better off leaving the  `/boot/efi/EFI/Boot` entirely alone as there are files in there that get used too.

Comment: I think the second one "EFI-PRE_RECASTUX" is unnecessary? When I changed my laptop battery, the system directly booted to windows and I ended up downloading recastux  disc image thinking it will fix the issue but I fixed it using some other command in Windows OS. So, should I delete that one? Not sure, if it is important or not.

Comment: Indeed anything not being used is to be deleted, I thought I had made it clear.

Comment: Additional info belongs in the question not as a comment.